# Python: program not writing to file after breaking the loop

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I am fairly new to Python, and I am messing around with code and I am wondering why my code, when the for loop is broken, does not write to the file.

But, when I do not break the for loop, it writes to the file over and over again with no end, deleting the previous content (I only want it to loop through once and get the data on the first iteration of it):

```
            def runExtract(self):
                 with open(self.fileIn) as f:
                    content = f.readlines()
                    #query = f.readlines()
                    for query in content:
                            result=google_search.SearchEngine.search(query, 3)
                            """junk"""
                            file1=open(self.fileOutGoog,'r+b')

                            """junk"""

                            for k in result:   
                                #file.write(str(k.name)+"\t")
                                file1.write(str(k.link)+"\t")
                                #file.write(str(k.description)+"\t")
                                file1.write("\n")
                                #file=open(self.fileOutGoog,'rb')

                            file1.flush() """writes to file, deleting the '/url?q=' from html"""
                            file1.close()
                            file1 = open(self.fileOutGoog,'r')
                            filedata = file1.read()
                            file1.close()

                            newdata = filedata.replace('/url?q=','')

                            file1 = open(self.fileOutGoog,'w')
                            file1.write(newdata)
                            file1.flush()
                            file1.close()


                            result=bing_search.SearchEngine.search(query, 3)
                            """junk"""
                            file2=open(self.fileOutBing,'w')

                            for k in result:
                                #file.write(str(k.name)+"\t")
                                file2.write(str(k.link)+"\t")
                               # file.write(str(k.description)+"\t")
                                file2.write("\n")

                            file2.flush()
                            file2.close()
                            break

                    print("done - check dir for results")
                    f.flush()
                    f.close()
```

I have been trying to fix this for two days straight, but I have not succeeded.

Comment: Have you tried using `with` for those other two files, as well? Also, are you 100% sure you are entering those loops at all, i.e. the big outer loop and the `for k...` loop writing data?

Comment: you are opening two files here. The first one you open in read mode, so I'm not sure why you try to write to it. The second one opens in write mode and truncates the file each time it does. You should refer to the official documentation and make sure you are using built in functions correctly: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: The loops are definitely being run, seeing that without breaking the for loop, it still writes teh data from the data I am accessing. The real problem here is that the data in the files get deleted after breaking from the for loop.

Comment: Also, intead of `for query in content: ... break` you could also do `query = next(content)` and go without the loop. Might be clearer then what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: If you remove the `break`, then `file2` will hold only the data from the last query; with the `break`, it holds only the data from the first. Maybe that's the problem? Is the first query's `result` empty?

Comment: have you done any debugging? If that's the case, I imagine `result` is probably empty on your first iteration

Comment: Hmm ok I will test it out once I am off the train, my computer ran out of battery. Thanks for all the help, I am sure it will work out! :)